# Prove that any first-order logics with equality and a relation/functional symbol of arity more than 1 is undecidable

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

**Definition**: A formal logic system is **decidable** – if there is an algorithm that can determine if any given sentence is a theorem (or not).

Based on this definition, I am not sure how to move to prove that, "any first-order logics with equality and a relation/functional symbol of arity more than 1." Example also can help if you can write one.

Thanks.

Comment: Example: How about the first-order axioms of Peano arithmetic?